# Main routine return value in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

I have a simple C program that just returns 0:

```
int main(void) {
   return 0;
}
```

After the translation into assembly language in gdb:

```
0x0000000100000fa0 <+0>:    push   rbp
0x0000000100000fa1 <+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x0000000100000fa4 <+4>:    xor    eax,eax
0x0000000100000fa6 <+6>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
0x0000000100000fad <+13>:   pop    rbp
0x0000000100000fae <+14>:   ret
```

There is an instruction at **0x100000fa6** which stores 0 (0x0) at [rbp-0x4].

I've noticed that the same function defined as

```
void main(void) {
   return ;
}
```

doesn't have that instruction.

As far as I know, the negative displacement is used inside of the stack frame to store/retrieve local variables of a routine. The function doesn't have any. **What is the purpose of the instruction? What is that 0 actually mean?**

To compile a program I used:

```bash
gcc main.c -o main -g -O0
```

My Os is macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: You are correct: it serves no purpose. Is this an optimized build?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, yeah! with ```-O0 ``` optimization flag

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3xz94zj9v)

Comment: What version of clang are you using?  Note that `-O0` disables optimizations so you should not call this an optimized build.  Try `-O1` or higher.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I'm using ```Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)```. I didn't call that program an optimized one, just wanted to figure out why that instruction is placed there. If I declare a local variable and initialize it, it will be placed at position [rbp-0x8], in case of `int`. The space is consumed and its value never used. Seems like it's just a way computers work :)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YsErzKqa5

Comment: @StonePaul Don't expect the compiler to generate good code if you tell it to turn off its brain (optimiser).

Comment: @fuz, It is exactly as I expected! Just want to know how it works under the hood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Stack is not only used for storing local variables, but also used for storing input and output of functions. That 0 is the return value of main. In the second case, main is defined as void, so it is not returning anything.

Another thing is, depending on ABI, return values and function inputs can be passed in registers. That `xor ax, ax` is there for this. Indeed, it is the real value that will be used, because the value on the stack is maintained only to support debugging using stack trace such as after a core dump, because register content can't be captured.

However according to latest C standard, main should be defined as either of these:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

So the program has undefined behavior main being defined as void.

Comment: I meant the usage of negative displacement for accessing/modifying/etc local variables. However, compiling with `-O1 -g` flag removes the aforementioned instruction. The question arises - **is the instruction necessary?** What is that magic 0 used for? If the function has `return 1;`, for example, the instruction probably would be ```mov   exa, 0x1```, therefore ```mov   [rpb-0x4]``` doesn't seem to contain return value. It would be great if you could explain it to me!

Comment: The behaviour of `main` having a different signature is implementation-defined, not undefined.  Implementations may define other legal signatures.  For example, UNIX platforms commonly have `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);`.